How to solve the partial differential equation?
I need to solve TeV[t,z] for laser heating plasma. And I took two steps: (1) solve the temperature at boundary TeV0[t]; (2) With TeV0[t] as boundary condition, solve TeV1[t,z]. However, the method of NDSolve does not work.  The problem might origin from complex value in the equations.
Could anyone figure it out? Thanks a lot!!!
(**at boundary**)
Z = 1; \[Lambda] = 1; n0 = 0.01; B = 10; E0 = 0.01; Temp0 = 100;
\[Nu][t_] := 1.72*Z*n0*\[Lambda]^-1*TeV[t]^(-3/2)

(**permittivity**)
\[Epsilon][t_] := 1 - n0/(1 - B + I *\[Nu][t])
\[Epsilon]R[t_] := 1 - (n0*(1 - B))/((1 - B)^2 + \[Nu][t]^2)
\[Epsilon]I[t_] := (n0*\[Nu][t])/((1 - B)^2 + \[Nu][t]^2)
\[Epsilon]0[t_] := (\[Epsilon]R[t]^2 + \[Epsilon]I[t]^2)^(
 1/2) (*\[Epsilon]0^2=\[Epsilon]*\[Epsilon]^**)

(***refractive index**)
k[t_] := \[Epsilon][t]^(1/2)
kR[t_] := Re[k[t]]
kI[t_] := Im[k[t]]

(**transmission**)
t0[t_] := 2/(1 + k[t])
t0t0[t_] := 4/(1 + 2 kR[t] + \[Epsilon]0[t])
\[Eta][t_] := (2 \[Nu][t])/((1 - B)^2 + \[Nu][t]^2)
(**electric field**)
EE[t_] := E0^2/\[Epsilon]0[t]^(1/2)
(**equations**)
wP[t_] := 3/2 n0*TeV[t]/(511*10^3)
wL[t_] := 1/2 (1 + \[Epsilon]R[t])*EE[t]
S[t_] := 1/2 kR[t]*EE[t]
wJ[t_] := 1/4 n0*\[Eta][t]*EE[t]
DS[t_] := kR[t]/(2 \[Epsilon]0[t]^(1/2)) EE[t]*(-2 kI[t])
pde = {D[wP[t] + wL[t], t] == DS[t] + wJ[t]};

ic = {TeV[0] == Temp0};
sol0 = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic}, TeV, {t, 0, 10^8}]
TeV0[t_] := sol0[t] // Re
Plot[{TeV0[t]}, {t, 0, 10^6}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10^6}, {0, 200}}, 
 Ticks -> Automatic]

(***inside plasma**)
n1[z_] := n0 + z;
\[Nu]1[t_, z_] := 1.72*Z*n1[z]*\[Lambda]^-1*TeV1[t, z]^(-3/2)

(**permittivity**)
\[Epsilon]1[t_, z_] := 1 - n1[z]/(1 - B + I *\[Nu]1[t, z])
\[Epsilon]1R[t_, z_] := 
 1 - (n1[z]*(1 - B))/((1 - B)^2 + \[Nu]1[t, z]^2)
\[Epsilon]1I[t_, z_] := (
 n1[z]*\[Nu]1[t, z])/((1 - B)^2 + \[Nu]1[t, z]^2)
\[Epsilon]10[t_, 
  z_] := (\[Epsilon]1R[t, z]^2 + \[Epsilon]1I[t, z]^2)^(
 1/2) (*\[Epsilon]0^2=\[Epsilon]*\[Epsilon]^**)

(***refractive index**)
k1[t_, z_] := \[Epsilon]1[t, z]^(1/2)
k1R[t_, z_] := Re[k1[t, z]]
k1I[t_, z_] := Im[k1[t, z]]

\[Eta]1[t_, z_] := (2 \[Nu]1[t, z])/((1 - B)^2 + \[Nu]1[t, z]^2)
(**electric field**)
fun1[t_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[-2*Im[k1[t, z1]], {z1, 0, z}]
E1E1[t_, z_] := E0^2/\[Epsilon]10[t, z]^(1/2) Exp[fun1[t, z]]

wP[t_, z_] := 3/2 n1[z]*TeV1[t, z]/(511*10^3)
wL[t_, z_] := 1/2 (1 + \[Epsilon]1R[t, z])*E1E1[t, z]
S[t_, z_] := 1/2 k1R[t, z]*E1E1[t, z]
wJ[t_, z_] := 1/4 n1[z]*\[Eta]1[t, z]*E1E1[t, z]
DS[t_, z_] := 
 D[k1R[t, z]/2 E0^2/\[Epsilon]10[t, z]^(1/2), z]*Exp[fun1[t, z]] + 
  k1R[t, z]/
   2 (E0^2/\[Epsilon]10[t, z]^(1/2)) ** Exp[fun1[t, z]]*(-2 k1I[t, z])

pde = {D[wP[t, z] + wL[t, z], t] == DS[t, z] + wJ[t, z]};

ic = {TeV1[0, z] == Temp0, TeV1[t, 0] == TeV0[t]};
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic}, TeV1, {t, 0, 10^8}, {z, 0, 10^2}]
Plot[{sol1[t]}, {t, 0, 10^6}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10^5}, {0, 200}}]

Or in simplified code with same problems
Z = 1; \[Lambda] = 1; n[z_] :=0.01+ z; B = 10; E0 = 0.01; TeV0 = 100;
\[Nu][t_, z_] := 1.72*Z*n[z]*\[Lambda]^-1*TeV[t, z]^(-3/2)
(**permittivity**)
\[Epsilon][t_, z_] := 1 - n[z]/(1 - B + I *\[Nu][t, z])
\[Epsilon]R[t_, z_] := 1 - (n[z]*(1 - B))/((1 - B)^2 + \[Nu][t, z]^2)
\[Epsilon]I[t_, z_] := (n[z]*\[Nu][t, z])/((1 - B)^2 + \[Nu][t, z]^2)
\[Epsilon]0[t_, z_] := (\[Epsilon]R[t, z]^2 + \[Epsilon]I[t, z]^2)^(
 1/2)

\[Eta][t_, z_] := (2 \[Nu][t, z])/((1 - B)^2 + \[Nu][t, z]^2)
(***refractive index**)
k[t_, z_] := (\[Epsilon][t, z])^(1/2)
kR[t_, z_] := Re[k[t, z]]
kI[t_, z_] := Im[k[t, z]]

(**electric field**)
fun[t_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(-2*kI[t, z1]), {z1, 0, z}]
E2[t_, z_] := E0^2/\[Epsilon]0[t, z]^(1/2) Exp[fun[t, z]]

wP[t_, z_] := 3/2 n[z]*TeV[t, z]/(511*10^3)
wL[t_, z_] := 1/2 (1 + \[Epsilon]R[t, z])*E2[t, z]
S[t_, z_] := 1/2 kR[t, z]*E2[t, z]
S[t_, z_] := 1/2 Re[k[t, z]]*E2[t, z]
wJ[t_, z_] := 1/4 n[z]*\[Eta][t, z]*E2[t, z]
DS[t_, z_] := 
 D[1/2*Re[k[t, z]]*E0^2/\[Epsilon]0[t, z]^(1/2), z]*Exp[fun[t, z]] + 
  E2[t, z]*(-2*Im[k[t, z]])
pde = {D[wP[t, z] + wL[t, z], t] == DS[t, z] + wJ[t, z]};
ic = {TeV[0, z] == TeV0, TeV[t, 0] == TeV0};
solT1 = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic}, TeV, {t, 0, 10^5}, {z, 0, 10^5}]
```


Is this somehow connected to your previous question?

@Domen Yes! I still can not solve that one.

So why are you opening a new question? How is it different than the previous one?

@Domen Because that question is not solved. I will delete that question.

No no no, that's not the way to do it ... Do not delete a question and repost the same one again. You already had a useful comment there.

@Domen  OK! I have taken the suggestions over there, and the questions are modified a bit.
